# device BOOTLOADER version number in android 1.6

Tags: android

how can i get bootloader version number in API level 3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible, since the Flag is only available in API level 8 and above. But maybe you could use something like this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Comment: Thanks @Roflcoptr. as per my understanding it is serial ID. correct me if i am wrong. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: Yes it is from the example there. You could also try this one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29 but this isn't working on all devices afaik.